# app Icon not changed in *Task Menu* in flutter?

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I have successfully changed the App Icon for the App by replacing the file with the files I downloaded from [here](https://romannurik.github.io/AndroidAssetStudio/icons-launcher.html#foreground.type=clipart&foreground.clipart=android&foreground.space.trim=1&foreground.space.pad=0.25&foreColor=rgba(96%2C%20125%2C%20139%2C%200)&backColor=rgb(68%2C%20138%2C%20255)&crop=0&backgroundShape=square&effects=none&name=ic_launcher).

Its working fine in the **Menu** with logo and name as expected.
but the icon is not changed in the **Task Menu**.[image]

And in the **Menu** its fine though.[image]

I replaced [***mipmap-hdpi, mipmap-mdpi, mipmap-xhdpi, mipmap-xxhdpi, mipmap-xxxxhdpi***] folders with new ones in the *android->app->src->main->res* path of my project.

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue. I **rebooted my smartphone** and it worked as it was suggested in related topics. After restart the icon is displayed as it should everywhere.

I attach related links:

[Problem ticket in Flutter Github repository](https://github.com/flutter/flutter/issues/25136)

[Related question with solution that worked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51569550/flutter-mini-icon-not-change)

Comment: Not only for Android but also in iOS, the same issue happened, the same solution was applied, then it's all good.

Answer (score 1):

Please check manifest file.

```
  <application
        android:name="io.flutter.app.FlutterApplication"
        android:label="flutter"
        android:icon="@mipmap/app_logo">
```

You have to change icon name here.

Comment: Name is there *ic_launcher* in manifest file, same as  in  mipmap folder. I don't think this is the reason. Because Icon is shown in the menu  but the problem is in the task menu.

Comment: The problem was that app was running in debug mode that is why it was having the *flutter* icon. But in the release mode it was working :)