# Change Flutter icon that shows when Overview button pressed in Android

Tags: icons, flutter

I performed the [Flutter Launcher Icons](https://pub.dartlang.org/packages/flutter_launcher_icons) procedure and it worked perfectly, all application icons have changed, after the images in the folders below have been changed by my icon:

mipmap-hdpi

mipmap-mdpi

mipmap-xhdpi

mipmap-xxhdpi

mipmap-xxxhdpi

However, there is 1 icon that is not being changed and I do not know how to change.

Below this image which remains of the flutter icon.

`Icon Flutter`: Flutter Demo

This icon should have changed since all the others were also

[image]

Could you tell me how you could handle this?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

This often happens as you OS caches few image assets. So, it's not flutter issue. What you can do is try rebooting, or completely uninstall and reinstall. That's how I fixed the issue. This frequently occurs with `Redmi` devices.