# Changing flutter android overview icon

Tags: android, flutter

I have used this package[https://pub.dev/packages/flutter_launcher_icons] to change the launcher icons, but the icon which shows up in the overview view, on tapping the onscreen overview button, still has the default flutter icon. How do I change the icon here? [image]

Comment: follow this step will work pretty well. https://github.com/fluttercommunity/flutter_launcher_icons

https://medium.com/@psyanite/how-to-add-app-launcher-icons-in-flutter-bd92b0e0873a

Comment: @AmitPrajapati I had been trying this for a couple of hours since yesterday, but it never seemed to work, However I checked now it seems to be fixed, idk how, thanks anyway

Comment: @ are you aware with Android app structure ?

Comment: @AmitPrajapati Just the super basics, why do you ask?

Comment: you can replace luncher icon with your over inside minmap all with same name

Comment: when i tried with 'flutter_launcher_icons' it did change the icon in those locations, but except for the overview view icon. Anyway its working now, maybe its a cache like thing.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Flutter - Mini Icon not change](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51569550/flutter-mini-icon-not-change)